# how do i set an object key and value based on two sets of input i am mapping on in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, frontend, flatten

[this is how it looks in ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CID7N.png)
The image shows the scenario. I made it work using debounce but that surely is not the final solution. i need to make an object in this structure based on what input user puts in these field.
{
propertyName: propertyValue,
propertyName: propertyValue,
propertyName: propertyValue,
propertyName: propertyValue,
propertyName: propertyValue,
}

Note that i have used only two sets of input which i am mapping on 5 times refer the code snippet for that

[this image is code for the ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmHRk.png)

Comment: You need to add your code , not screenshots

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.